# Send Metadata into "Pre token generation" trigger with REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I use AWS Cognito for my apps, and actually have 3 apps working with the same user's Cognito database. This three apps are connected, so the auth is shared. But based on what app you are logging in from, I customize the AccessToken with different params.

When I login, I send a Client Metadata that looks like this:

```
{
  platform: 'ANY_OF_THE_3_PLATFORMS'
}
```

So that when the authentication process gets to the  **Pre token generation** trigger, I check the ClientMetadata and I know where the user is coming from so that I can make changes.

Everything works great until I get to the refresh token process. When the token is refreshed, the ClientMetadata I attach is not received by the **Pre token generation** trigger, so that I don't know where this refresh token request is coming from and therefore I can't customize the AccessToken.

Any solution or workaround?

I have seen in the official docs that **REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH** should trigger the **Pre authentication trigger**, which includes the Client Metadata, but it actually doesn't. I don't know if this is a AWS error, or I misunderstood something.

Thanks to whoever can save my day!